# If $A \subset \omega$ and $A \neq \emptyset$ then $\bigcup A=A$ then $A= \omega$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

**Definition.** $\bigcup A = \{ x | \exists a \in A \mbox{ such that } x \in a\}$

**Problem.** If $A \subset \omega$ and $A \neq \emptyset$ Prove, if $\bigcup A=A$ then $A= \omega$

**Attempt.** Suppose that $A \neq \omega$ then $\omega -A \neq \emptyset$ and $\omega-A \subset \omega$ then exists $n_0 = \mbox{ min } (\omega-A)$ so, $\forall n \in \omega: n=n_{0} \mbox{ or } n_{0} \in n$.

Then, if there is $m \in A$ such that $n_{0} \in m$ so, $n_{0} \in \bigcup A $ then $n_{0} \in A$ because $\bigcup A = A$ then $\forall m \in A: n_{0} \notin n$, so $\forall m \in A: m \in n_{0} \mbox{ or } n_{0}=m$ but if $n_{0} = m \in A$ is a contradiction so $\forall m \in A: m \in n_{0}.$

But I don't see a contradiction, could you help me?

Comment: Better to use $\bigcup A$ `\bigcup A` than $\cup A$ `\cup A`.  (Aside from the size, note the different spacing corresponding to the different semantics of the operators.)

Comment: Why do you have two thens?

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is a set of transitive sets, then $\bigcup A$ is transitive. If $\bigcup A=A$, then $A$ is transitive. And it is a transitive set of ordinals, so it is an ordinal.

So either $A\in\omega$, or $A=\omega$. Now show that if $A\in\omega$, then $\bigcup A\neq A$.

Comment: Why $A$ is a set of transitive sets?

Comment: Last I checked, ordinals are transitive, and if $A\subseteq\omega$, then $A$ is a set of ordinals... :-)

Comment: what do you mean of tansitive set?

Comment: What do you mean by "ordinal"?

Comment: $\alpha$ is an ordinal if  $E=\{(x,y): x \in y\}$ connects $\alpha$ and $\forall a \in \alpha$ implies $a \subset \alpha$

Comment: The latter is called "transitivity".

Comment: $E$ connects $\alpha$ if $\forall u,v \in \alpha$ $ u \in v \mbox{ or } v \in u \mbox{ or } u=v $

Comment: Wich one Asaf karagila?

Comment: The latter, for every $a\in\alpha$, $a\subseteq\alpha$.

Comment: ok but if $A \subset \omega $ not necessarily $A \in  \omega$

Comment: Yes. I know. Read my answer again.

Comment: What I have, in terms that you describe, is if A is transtive then $\bigcup A \subset A$ but not transitive.

Comment: No. What I said was that if $A$ is a set, and for every $a\in A$, $a$ is transitive, then $\bigcup A$ is transitive.